# Gmail SMTP, CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH XOAUTH2, SMTP ERROR: AUTH command failed: 334

Tags: php, wordpress, oauth-2.0, smtp, gmail

I am trying to hook in [Gmail SMTP v1.1.7 plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gmail-smtp/).

I have already successfully activated it by going to google developer console, getting OAuth key

[image]

then connecting the plugin with Gmail

[image]

However when I try to send test email I get Authentication error

> Server Info
>   2018-04-15 00:46:32 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ( 'ssl' => array ( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true, ),)
>   2018-04-15 00:46:33 Connection: opened
>   2018-04-15 00:46:33 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
>   2018-04-15 00:46:33 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP e77sm21399032pfk.147 - gsmtp"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP e77sm21399032pfk.147 - gsmtp
>   2018-04-15 00:46:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 35882577"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]250-SIZE 35882577"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
>   2018-04-15 00:46:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 35882577"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]250-SIZE 35882577"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8"
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [113.166.92.87]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 Auth method requested: XOAUTH2
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN,PLAIN,XOAUTH2,PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN,OAUTHBEARER,XOAUTH
>   2018-04-15 00:46:36 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH XOAUTH2 [somethingEncriptedHere]=
>   2018-04-15 00:46:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
>   2018-04-15 00:46:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 [somethingShorteEncriptedHere]=="
>   2018-04-15 00:46:36 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 [somethingShorteEncriptedHere]==
>   2018-04-15 00:46:36 SMTP ERROR: AUTH command failed: 334 [somethingShorterEncriptedHere]==
>   SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
>   2018-04-15 00:46:36 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

It then tries to use Username and password but fails too.

Relevant part of the log is

> 2018-04-15 00:46:35 Auth method requested: XOAUTH2    //negotiates the method of authentication
>   2018-04-15 00:46:35 Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN,PLAIN,XOAUTH2,PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN,OAUTHBEARER,XOAUTH    //negotiates the method of authentication
>   2018-04-15 00:46:36 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH XOAUTH2 [somethingEncriptedHere]=    //sends encrypted client secret(my guess)
>   2018-04-15 00:46:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
>   2018-04-15 00:46:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 [somethingShorterEncriptedHere]=="
>   2018-04-15 00:46:36 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 [somethingShorterEncriptedHere]==
>   2018-04-15 00:46:36 SMTP ERROR: AUTH command failed: 334 [somethingShorterEncriptedHere]==    //fails
>   SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
>   2018-04-15 00:46:36 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

I am not sure why does it fail on authentication if it already has successfully connected/registered the Gmail plugin with gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out myself

It would appear that email has to be one that I have connected web application to (`xxxxx@gmail.com`), not the one that looks like `xxxxx@smtp-xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

In other words you will be able to connect plugin to gmail API with incorrect email, but it will fail at sending emails later.

Answer (score 0):

First you can check the API and you can check this in another web-server.
Did you give permission google API for your own web-site?
If anything is not working fine, maybe you have to check your plugin version.